# Calculation of atomic spectrum

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, software, quantum-chemistry

I need to calculate spectrum of Hg atom (wavelength and transition intensity), taking into account relativistic corrections. Can someone suggest a software or a package for atomic spectroscopy, that I could use for numerical calculations.

P.S. I tried the Grasp 2K package, but somehow I cannot run rcsfexcitation and hence examples provided with the package.

Comment: There is the _ab initio_ Hartree-Fock code by Bob Cowan. Steep learning curve to handle that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a look now.